# Combining Multiple UV Maps for export

Tags: texturing

I have a model which has 3 UV maps which I need to export to another 3d program(modo) but am unsure how to go about it. I need to export as a .obj file but do not think this can handle multiple uv's. Is there a way to merge these maps into 1 map? Please be gentle as I am a beginner with blender and still feeling my way.

TIA

Cheers
Damo

Comment: Try exporting to FBX file format instead, I think it supports multiple UV maps per mesh.

Comment: I'm pretty sure .obj supports multiple maps, but I know for sure .fbx does. It may be a problem with the importer, not the exporter.

Comment: Create a new Image and Bake the textures.

Comment: Hi i dont have time to explain how it works but have a look at this, there should be a video to tell u how to use it https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?339369-MultiEdit-%28alpha-1%29-Multiple-Objects-Editing

Answer (score 1):

Blender has an add-on for Combining multiple UV maps into one. Texture Atlas.
[image: TextureAtlas addon for unwrapping and baking of Shadowmaps/LightMaps of entire scene]

The addon Documentation has some tutorial Videos on how to do that.
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/TextureAtlas

Comment: This isn't actually what he should be doing even though he mentioned it. You may want to read the question again.

Answer (score 1):

I use 'bake' to turn everything into a single texture.

First you have to go to 'UV Maps' and create a new UV. I used the name 'UVBake', but it can be anything.
[image]

Now select the entire mesh, press the 'U' and 'Unwrap' key.

Now in the 'UV Image editor' create a new image.
[image]

Now in the rendering panel, go to 'Bake' and select 'Textures'.
[image]

Click on 'Bake' and you will get all the textures in a single image. Save it.
[image]

Now you can delete all the materials that belonged to your object, and create a new material.
[image]
[image]

Create a new texture and select the one you made. ////////////////////
[image]

If you did everything right, you'll get the same result in just a single texture.
[image]

Now simply export your object the way you prefer.